# Custom arguments in custom API Platform action

Tags: php, rest, symfony4, api-platform.com

I'm currently working with **API Platform** and **Symfony 4**.

### Scenario:

I want to generate a key (a random string) and add connect a specific user to it. So I created two classes called `KeyGenerator` and `KeyManager`. The `KeyManager` contains a function which creates a key object of a `DownloadKey` class using the `KeyGenerator` and adds a user to it which is loaded by its username.

The `DownloadKey` class is an `APIResource` and contains the following attributes:

- createdAt
- updatedAt
- owner
- key

I created a custom action following the **API Platform** documentation. And I can see that it's called, when I open the related URL.

### Problem:

I don't want to use the default arguments (listed above) to create a new download key. I just want to create it by passing a username within the POST body (**not in the URL**). But either I don't search correctly or it's rarely documented how to **add custom parameters to POST-requests**.

So I would be glad if anyone can tell if he has any experience with custom parameters and descriptions with **API Platform**.

I hope, I described my problem detailed enough.

Comment: An API Platform controller is just a Symfony controller. You can use the $request object to access POST data or anything else.